# System.web.security.Roles.isUserInRole(Username, rolename) gives System.NULLReferenceException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, roleprovider

I'm using the default SqlRoleProvider for my ASP.Net Web API application. 
In login request I try to find if user is in specific role as following:-

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole(username, rolename) == false)
    throw new Exception("User needs specific role to access.");
```

The call to "Roles.IsUserInRole(username, rolename)" throws NULLReferenceException. 
I don't know why it is throwing that. I checked Roles and it has Provider = AspNetSqlRoleProvider.

web.config settings:-

```
<roleManager enabled="true" />
```

I've referenced "System.Web v4.0.0.0" from Assembly. Also, I've already tried to remove it and add it again.

It would be of great help if somebody can help me with that issue.

Thanks in advance